# Different counting for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, count, counter

If i have 2 parallel arrays. One is is short[] and other String[]. short has a range of marks.
short[95, 96, 95, 99, 100]. String has names of students [Mark, Steve, Emma, Rachael, Justin]
They have already been declared and are corresponding. I know how to sort alphabetically and according marks. The question asks me to print out " * " for the times a student has received a grade. The user does not put any input in. for example: This would be the output.

```
100 = * (As only 1 person got a 100)
99 = *
96 = *
95 = **
```

I have to get to that output without any user inputs. 
I kinda think i have an idea of how to do it but im pretty lost. I dont even know how to start. All i know is a counter has to be used but that would only work if a user inputs a mark. I dont know how to do it without any input.

Comment: Do you want to generate a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)?

Comment: yes @Kninnug i think thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming - no of students = no

and your 2 arrays are

```
String [] students;
```

and

```
short [] marks.
```

Create a third array

```
int [] count = new int[101];


int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < no; ++i)
    ++count[marks[i]];
```

count array will contain no of times each mark occurs
i.e. count[50] will contain no of students who got 50.

You can print it out as

```
for(int i = 0; i < no; ++i)
    System.out.println(i + " = " + count[i]);
```

Comment: Is the first loop really necessary? I thought Java initialized the `int`s to zero automagically.

Comment: i understand that, what is the [101] for?

Comment: @Kninnug habit from c++, updated.

Comment: @user2278109 there are 101 possible marks a user can get 0, 1, 2 --- 100. Try out the code and see.

Comment: oh rite i get it! thanks, only new to java so still a bit confused about everything

Comment: @user93353 It's a good habit though ;)

Comment: it says cannot convert from int to String? is there a way around this? @user93353

Comment: @user2278109 - what line gives that error?

Comment: ++count[marks[i]]; @user93353

Comment: What have you declared `count` as. And what have you declared `marks` as?

Comment: count is String as using a method and passing down the String[]users array

Comment: I have declared count in my answer - it has to be an array of ints - `int [] count = new int[101];`

Comment: okay thanks, i'll play around with it and figure it out! @user93353 thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, such that the 100th index corresponds to the grade 100, the 99th index corresponds to the grade 99, etc.  This way if somebody gets a grade `g` you can just increment the gth element of the array.